# Where is PropertyChanged?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

Somehow I cannot see "`PropertyChanged`".

Any clue how to restore it?

[image]

Also I get the errror

> Error al crear 'System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger' a partir del
>   texto 'PropertyChanged'. [Line: 50 Position: 12]

Comment: Strange. If you write it on your own, do you get any compilation errors? Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: sometimes intellisense is stupid

Comment: @Muad'Dib Hmm But has a compilation error as well because of this issue.

Comment: @surfen Yup! I did all things...

Comment: So what's the compilation error? Is there a tooltip if you hover over UpdateSourceTrigger?

Comment: Purchance is this a Windows Phone App?

Comment: @sufen Error: Error al crear 'System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger' a partir del texto 'PropertyChanged'. [Line: 50 Position: 12]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight 4.0 [doesn't have it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#updating_the_data_source). Use [SL 5](http://i1.silverlight.net/content/downloads/SL5Final_RTW.docx) or [implement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92148/Updating-Source-on-PropertyChanged-on-Silverlight) an attached property that provides it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the input! But can you point me exactly where MSDN says that SL4 has only 2 options for the PropertyChanged property?

Comment: Yeah! I found this article http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2011/09/ngtweet-part-11-silverlight-5.html But this is strange that my partner has working this property and I have the same code by SVN ...

Comment: @Peretz glad I could help you. As I pointed out SL4 did not have this setting, while WPF an SL5 do offer this option. I was looking for a concrete statement from MS directly, but the best I could find was the SL5 feature list, which actually on the first page - well it said they added it, so it musn't have been there :-) - and the except from the doc, which also hints on that.

Comment: Thanks! I found exactly MSDN link (at the bottom) which says it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.95).aspx#1    The value PropertyChanged is not supported in Silverlight 4.